# Error at the end of APC install

Tags: fedora

I need to get APC running for a Drupal install of mine. I found a fairly concise guide at http://blog.4rev.net/2009-09/installing-apc-accelerator-into-php5-fedora-core-11/ for installing on FC11, only, I am using FC12. I figured I would give it a shot.

I was able to run the following commands successfully - and yum installed fc12 versions of everything in the FC11 guide.

```
 yum install php-pear

    yum install php-devel httpd-devel

    yum groupinstall ‘Development Tools’

    yum groupinstall ‘Development Libraries’
```

Then, I tried **pecl install apc**. Everything looked good until to got to the end, where it outputted the following error.

```
/var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c: In function ‘zif_apc_compile_file’:
/var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c:881: warning: unused variable ‘eg_class_table’
/var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c:881: warning: unused variable ‘eg_function_table’
/var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c: At top level:
/var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c:959: error: duplicate ‘static’
make: *** [php_apc.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Some people have had success with installing apc-beta, but that didn't work for me..

Any suggestions? Is there something I missed that is critical in the FC12 version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what worked for me..

```
# # install APC package  
# yum install php-pecl-apc  
#   
# # install gd package to have graphs in APC dashboard (optional)  
# yum install php-gd
```

I found this at..
http://www.redips.net/wordpress/make-it-faster/

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this and reinstall the APC(make sure that EAccelerator removed from php),before reinstall the APC install the following packages :-

## yum install pcre-devel

before installing APC.

On Debian use

## aptitude install libpcre3-dev

Then you will get the following response when you reinstall the APC :-

Answer (score 0):

another solution that worked for me was to edit the file /var/tmp/APC/php_apc.c and remove "static" from line 959. then i ran make and make install and it worked.

Comment: This seems very likely to be specific to a particular version of the code. Could you give more context?